# Desktop shortcut doesn't show up in the Windows 8 Metro UI

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I've installed a few of our applications on Windows 8 and I could confirm the shortcut in the Metro UI was created in here:

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs

The problem is:
When I installed the applications in Audit mode, the shortcuts (the tile) in the Metro UI  didn't show up for all the users created in the OOBE mode.

However, when I installed the applications in OOBE mode, the shortcuts always show up.

Does anyone know why?